# Conditional extraction of files from an Archive file

Tags: python, bash, gzip, python-2.x, tar

I have a large tar.gz archive file having `nxml` files and total size is around 5gb.
My aim is to extract files from it but, I do not have to extract all of them. I have to extract all those files whose name is greater than a threshold value.

For example:
Let us consider 1000 is our threshold value. So
`path/to/file/900.nxml` will not be extracted but
`path/to/file/1100.nxml` will be extracted.

So my requirement is to make a conditional extraction of files from the archive.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `tar -tf <archive>` to get a list of files in the archive.
2. Process the list of files to determine those you need to extract. Write the file list to a temporary file `<filelist>`, one line per file.

   - Looking at the tags you chose, you can use either Python or bash for this string filtering, whichever you prefer.
3. Use `tar -xf <archive> -T <filelist>` to extract the files you need.
   The option `-T` or `--files-from` reads the filenames to process from the given file.

   - See also the [manpage for tar](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).

Comment: Thanks,
As I said that I have around 500 thousand files in the archive, so is there any limitation for the command `tar -xf <archive> file1 file2 ...`
If so, can you please mention the limit, so that I can do the extraction in phases.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I've updated my answer. The option `--files-from` (short `-T`) is what you'll need to overcome limits on the length of a command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `--wildcards` option of tar.
For example in the case when your threshold is 1000 you can use `tar -xf tar.gz --wildcards path/to/files/????*.nxml`. The `?` will match one character and using `*` will match any number of character. This pattern will look for any file name with 4 or more characters.
Hope this helps.